# What pattern to use for TwilioRestClient with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to understand how to properly use the `TwilioRestClient` with Dependency Injection. I read this page announcing the [AddTwilioClient](https://www.twilio.com/blog/whats-new-in-twilio-helper-library-for-aspnet-v6) service and did some experiments.

The goal is to access multiple Twilio subaccounts.

*Program.cs:*

```
///Removed code for clarity
var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
  services.AddHttpClient();
  services.AddTwilioClient();
  services.AddScoped<TwilioVoiceServices>();
}).Build();
```

Here is an injected class that shows the two options for creating the `TwilioClient`

*TwilioVoiceService.cs*:

```
public class TwilioVoiceServices
{
  ///Removed code for clarity
  private readonly ITwilioRestClient twilioClient

  public TwilioVoiceServices(ITwilioRestClient twilioClient)
  {    
    _twilioClient = twilioClient;
  }

  public async Task<CallResource> GetCallWithNamedHttpClient(string accountSid, string authToken, string callSid)
  {
    var call = await CallResource.FetchAsync(
      pathAccountSid: accountSid,
      pathSid: callSid,                                
      client: new TwilioRestClient(username: accountSid, password: authToken, httpClient: _twilioClient.HttpClient);
      return call;
  }

  public async Task<CallResource> GetCallWithImpliedHttpClient(string accountSid, string authToken, string callSid)
  {      
    var call = await CallResource.FetchAsync(
      pathAccountSid: accountSid,
      pathSid: callSid,                                
      client: new TwilioRestClient(username: accountSid, password: authToken));
      return call;
  }
}
```

Both `GetCallWithNamedHttpClient` and `GetCallWithImpliedHttpClient` work and allow me to access the Twilio REST API using a dynamically named Sid/AuthToken.

Do I need to specify the httpClient: as the injected `ITwilioRestClient` as shown in `GetCallWithNamedHttpClient`? Or, does the Twilio library take care of that automatically as shown in `GetCallWithImpliedHttpClient`?

Since both work, my concern is that the `GetCallWithImpliedHttpClient` is actually creating new `HttpClient`s behind the scenes and not reusing the singleton `HttpClient` that `services.AddTwilioClient()` creates.

This is deployed to an Azure Function on .NET 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.AddTwilioClient()` from the `Twilio.AspNet.Core` library, the Twilio REST client will use the `IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient("Twilio")` to get the `HttpClient`. ([Source code](https://github.com/twilio-labs/twilio-aspnet/blob/141058c1b538b3c78cb4b08992b19cc7d24b0566/src/Twilio.AspNet.Core/TwilioClientDependencyInjectionExtensions.cs#L121))

So in `GetCallWithNamedHttpClient` you will be reusing that same `HttpClient` managed by the HTTP client factory, while in `GetCallWithImpliedHttpClient` it will create a new `HttpClient` every time. ([Source code](https://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20HttpClient%20=%20httpClient%20??%20DefaultClient();))

Reusing the HTTP client provided by the HTTP client factory would be better, so I'd go with `GetCallWithNamedHttpClient`, however, instead of injecting the `ITwilioRestClient`, I'd request an HTTP client from the HTTP client factory and pass that into the constructor of `TwilioRestClient`. Like this:

```cs
public class TwilioVoiceServices
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public TwilioVoiceServices(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<CallResource> GetCallWithNamedHttpClient(string accountSid, string authToken, string callSid)
    {
        var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        var call = await CallResource.FetchAsync(
            pathAccountSid: accountSid,
            pathSid: callSid,
            client: new TwilioRestClient(
                username: accountSid,
                password: authToken,
                httpClient: new SystemNetHttpClient(httpClient)
            )
        );
        return call;
    }
}
```

Now you don't really need to call `.AddTwilioClient` during startup since you're not injecting `ITwilioRestClient` anymore.

---

In this case, I think it makes even more sense to create a factory class for the Twilio client:

```cs
public class TwilioClientFactory
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public TwilioClientFactory(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public ITwilioRestClient CreateClient(string accountSid, string authToken)
    {
        var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        return new TwilioRestClient(
            username: accountSid,
            password: authToken,
            httpClient: new SystemNetHttpClient(httpClient)
        );
    }
}
```

Register the factory as a singleton and inject it anywhere you need it, call `CreateClient` and pass it into the resource methods:

```cs
var twilioClient = twilioClientFactory.CreateClient(
    accountSid: "", 
    authToken: ""
);
var call = await CallResource.FetchAsync(
    pathSid: "",
    client: twilioClient
);
```

Note that I'm not specifying the `accountSid` since it'll use the `twilioClient.AccountSid`.

---

If you only have a couple of accounts, it may be useful to subclass the Twilio client and add those subclasses to the DI container, like this:

```cs
using Twilio.AspNet.Core;
using Twilio.Clients;
using Twilio.Http;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHttpClient();

        var config = context.Configuration;

        var ivrClientOptions = config.GetSection("Twilio:Client:Ivr").Get<TwilioClientOptions>();
        services.AddScoped<IvrTwilioClient>(provider => new IvrTwilioClient(
            username: ivrClientOptions.AccountSid,
            password: ivrClientOptions.AuthToken,
            httpClient: new SystemNetHttpClient(provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient())
        ));

        var sipClientOptions = config.GetSection("Twilio:Client:Sip").Get<TwilioClientOptions>();
        services.AddScoped<SipTwilioClient>(provider => new SipTwilioClient(
            username: sipClientOptions.AccountSid,
            password: sipClientOptions.AuthToken,
            httpClient: new SystemNetHttpClient(provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient())
        ));
    }).Build();

public class IvrTwilioClient : TwilioRestClient
{
    public IvrTwilioClient(
        string username,
        string password,
        string accountSid = null,
        string region = null,
        Twilio.Http.HttpClient httpClient = null,
        string edge = null
    )
        : base(username, password, accountSid, region, httpClient, edge)
    {
    }
}

public class SipTwilioClient : TwilioRestClient
{
    public SipTwilioClient(
        string username,
        string password,
        string accountSid = null,
        string region = null,
        Twilio.Http.HttpClient httpClient = null,
        string edge = null
    )
        : base(username, password, accountSid, region, httpClient, edge)
    {
    }
}
```

Now you can have `IvrTwilioClient` and `SipTwilioClient` injected anywhere.

---

You can also use a combination of the above approaches.

Comment: Swimburger, thank you for the detailed reply and the code example. Two of my use cases with multiple subaccounts. First, one azure function that Twilio calls as a webhook for status events. This one function logs Twilio Sids from multiple subaccounts and then acts upon incoming Sid using the REST Api which could belong to any subaccount. The second, is one subaccount for a customer's IVR (which enqueues a caller to hold) and another subaccount has the Twilio SIP endpoints. To bridge a caller multiple Account Sids must be acted upon using the REST Api.

Comment: Swimburger, I need to read more about HttpClientFactory. I am not understanding why this line "httpClient: new SystemNetHttpClient(httpClient)" in your proposed solution doesn't create a new HttpClient on each call.

Comment: I added an example for having specific IVR vs SIP clients in DI, but for the webhook it makes most sense to use the `TwilioClientFactory` method.

Comment: `SystemNetHttpClient` is a wrapper class by Twilio for historical reasons that isn't really important, but it is required :) The built-in HTTP client factory will make sure the the `HttpClient` is being properly reused and refreshed for optimal performance. More info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain and the code. I made some adjustments and put into a sandbox app - so far so good. This is now the Internet's best resource on how to do Dependency Injection with TwilioRestClient.